# How to make the look of the labels text in VB.NET compare to Vb 6?

Tags: vb6, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I have a problem in th UI of the labels where the Labels look good when compared to the labels text in vb.net after it is migrated. I have checked the labels properties every things looks correct.

Can any one help how to make the labels to look as VB 6 labels?What is the reason we are unable to get the same label look in VB.NET?
Here Am adding the images also

[image]

Comment: Can you post some pictures of how it looks and how you want it to look?

Comment: added image for reference

Comment: Are you calling `EnableVisualStyles()` in your main program?

Comment: Yes calling in the main startup form.

Comment: Remove the call to EnableVisualStyles then and see if that has the desired effect..

Comment: No @StuartDunkeld I have tried that also but no use :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22583/discussion-between-jai-ganesh-and-stuart-dunkeld)

Comment: It looks to me (from your images) like a text spacing issue

Comment: Is it definitely the same font size and font name etc?

Comment: Yes It is same font size and name. :-)

Comment: Try setting the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` property of the Label to `True`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the font to a truetype font and standard font size, such as Arial 9pt. After conversion, sometimes the fonts are not anti-aliased. You might need to change this in more than one place, such as the form, the controls, and containers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same font may help. VB6 defaults to "MS Sans Serif" (on my system) whereas Visual Studio.Net defaults to "Microsoft Sans Serif".
These are NOT the same font, the former is a raster font and the latter is an open type font so will take advantage of ClearType aliasing.

Ideally, you would sent the font name to "Ms Shell Dlg" at run time which will be replaced with the default system font for the version of Windows you're running.